# Hibernate and Spring Transaction Manager: Transaction Not Successfully Started

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I have a Generic Repository with a method named saveList(). The purpose of this method is to take a List and persist it in "chunks" of 500 objects. Unfortunately, I'm getting a "TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started" when I get to the commit.

Everything I've seen says that this is a result of the Spring Transaction Manager. Unfortunately, for this particular method, I need to manually control the transaction.

Relevant code is below:

```
// from generic non-abstract repository
@Transactional
public void saveList(List<T> objectList) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    int i = 1;
    for (T obj : objectList) {

        session.save(obj);
        //sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(obj);
        i++;
        if (i % 500 == 0) {
            session.flush();
            //sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
        }
    }
    if (!tx.wasCommitted()) {
        tx.commit();
    }
    //sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Configuration from applicationContext.xml:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using both declarative and programmatic transaction demarcation. Get rid of the `session.beginTransaction()` and related method calls. Only use @Transactional.

Comment: Okay, I'll take your word for it, since you ARE the one who taught me Spring lo those many years ago in SCE. Unfortunately, I get the same error whether I use the annotation or not.

Comment: Hmm... Jason... Ferguson? Small world, huh? The "Transaction not successfully started" error comes from hibernate when you try to commit a transaction that either wasn't begun or was already committed/rolled back. As originally posted, your manual `tx.commit()` would be followed by another commit as a result of @Transactional. You must still somehow have the transaction being committed twice.

Comment: Oh, and btw, `session.flush()` doesn't "persist" anything. It just forces hibernate to issue statements to the database. It's not the same as a commit.

Comment: I found that in my application context, I had a <tx:advice> that was advising everything in the class (technically, everything in the interface it implements). I commented out the <tx:method> that applied, but now I get an UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only.

Comment: That mostly happens when you try to commit a transaction that's already been marked for rollback, probably because an exception was thrown.

Comment: Figured that, but UnexpectedRollbackException isn't wrapping another Exception in this case, so figuring out what other exception is being thrown is non-trivial.

Comment: The rollback exception only happens on a commit. The exception that marked the tx as "rollback only" would have happened earlier.

Comment: Gang's all here, it seems. I ended up doing this manually as a looped call to save(). The import feature is intended to be an uncommon operation, so pounding and pounding on it was not an effective use of time.

Answer (score 2):

Use openSession method to get session object and close it when you finished your work. It will work perfectly. For Example

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you must use a manual transaction, then get rid of the declarative `@Transactional` option at the top.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see the point of doing this, since the session is not cleared between the flushes (and will thus need as much memory as if you let Hibernate flush at the end of the transaction), but if you really want to do this, and just want a new transaction just for this method, just annotate the method with

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

and forget about the Hibernate transaction management.

This will make Spring pause the current transaction (if any), start a new transaction, execute your method and commit/rollback the new transaction, and then resume the paused transaction (if any).

Comment: I had removed the call to session.clear() for some reason or another, thanks for the reminder to put it back.